# Formal for "move the focus from A to B"?

Tags: word-choice, formality

What is a formal way of saying "move the focus from A to B" in the following context?

> The two curves swap their locations when we **move our focus from measure A to measure
>   B**.

My some lousy solutions are

1. The two curves swap their locations **when we switch from measure A to measure B**.
2. The two curves swap their locations **when we focus on measure A instead of measure B**.

Comment: "*Shift* the focus." See Collocations: shift the focus (of something) the focus shifts (from something) (to something) "The focus of the conference shifted from population growth to the education of women."  LDOCE http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/focus_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two curves **transpose** when we **shift focus** from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

The expression *move the focus* is correct - see [definition #2 (Macmillan)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/focus_2) .

Other options are *change the focus* and *shift the focus*. The last one is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move%20the%20focus%2C%20shift%20the%20focus%2C%20change%20the%20focus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmove%20the%20focus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshift%20the%20focus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchange%20the%20focus%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Ngrams chart]